# How to track mouse in a complete circle in openGL/GLUT?

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glut

I have a problem with the mouse tracking in my program, in the first vertical half of the screen it works normal, but when i cross the vertical middle of the screen it doesn't work in the right direction.

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(
              0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f,
              0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glRotatef(xrot, 0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    drawBox();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


void idle()
{
    if (!mouseDown)
    {
        xrot += 0.0f;
        yrot += 0.0f;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        mouseDown = true;

        xdiff = x - yrot;
        ydiff = -y + xrot;
    }
    else
        mouseDown = false;
}

void mouseMotion(int x, int y)
{
    if (mouseDown)
    {
        yrot = x - xdiff;
        xrot = y + ydiff;

        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutCreateWindow("Still not working");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMotion);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    //glutIdleFunc(idle);

    if (!init())
        return 1;

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote the program above, but still learning this whole openGL language, so if you have any idea, thank you!

Comment: I want to rotate the object what I created with Bezier curvess , in the middle of the screen, while I hold my mouse button. The problem is that I can only rotate it to maybe 180 degrees and if I move the mouse toward it rotates backward! 

Comment: To rotate only in circle you do following,

Get the screen co-ordinates of mouse click start and top  then project these two points on to the sphere see how to do sphere mapping. Then after sphere mapped start and end points define rotation quaternion and use it to calculate and update camera Up, Direction and right vectors and use it and new View Matrix.